# Second derivative of a parametric equation with trig functions

Tags: calculus, parametric

I am solving a problem where I have to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ given these parametric equations:

$ x = \cos t $
$ y = 3 \sin t $

I got $-3\operatorname{cot}t\;$ for the first derivative by finding $\frac{dy}{dt} / \frac{dx}{dt}$.

For the second derivative, I simply took the derivative of $-3\operatorname{cot}t$ to get $3\operatorname{csc}^2t$.

However, my teacher did this differently. He wrote that $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{-3(-\operatorname{csc}^2t)}{-\sin t} = -3\operatorname{csc}^3t$

I'd really appreciate it if someone could explain where I went wrong in my own solution.

Thanks $:)$

Comment: Are you sure you mean $d^2x/dy^2$ instead of $d^2y/dx^2$ ?

Comment: The last equation is wrong. $\frac{\csc^2}{\sin} = \frac{\cos^2/ \sin^2}{\sin} = \frac{\cos^2}{\sin^3} \neq \frac{\cos^3}{\sin^3} = \csc^3$

Comment: Mr_e_man, you are correct. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You took the derivative with respect to $t$. Your teacher took the derivative with respect to $x$.
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -3\cot t$$
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right) = \frac{\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)}{\frac{dx}{dt}} = \frac{\frac{d}{dt}(-3\cot t)}{-\sin t} = \frac{3\csc^2 t}{-\sin t}$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$\eqalign{
\def\L{\left} \def\R{\right}
\def\b#1{\color{blue}{#1}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
&\b{9x^2 + y^2 = 9} \;=\; \L(9 \cos^2 t + 9\sin^2t\R) \\
}$$
This can be *implicitly* differentiated to yield
$$\eqalign{
0 &= 18x\:dx + 2y\:dy \\
\c{dy} &\c{= -\L(\frac{9x}{y}\R) dx} \\
\frac{dy}{dx} &= -\frac{9x}y \;=\; p \\
}$$
Further implicit differentiation yields
$$\eqalign{
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
dp
 &= -9\L(\frac{dx}{y}\R) + 9\L(\frac{x\,\c{dy}}{y^2}\R) \\
 &= -9\L(\frac{dx}{y}\R) \c{-} 9\L(\frac{x\;\c{9x\,dx}}{y^2\,\c{y}}\R) \\
 &= -9\L(\frac{\b{y^2 + 9x^2}}{y^3}\R)dx \\
 &= -9\L(\frac{\b9}{y^3}\R)dx \\
\frac{dp}{dx} &= -\L(\frac{81}{y^3}\R) \;=\; \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} \\
\\
}$$
To recover your teacher's answer substitute $\:y=3\sin t$